# Flutter PageView itemCount change causes PageController jumpToPage to jump to wrong page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

I have one PageView that handles three Lists of data that are different lengths. List one has one item, list 2 has 2 items and list 3 has 3 items. Here is what is happening.

1. PageView gets built with list 1 itemCount = 1 and page 0.
2. PageView gets built with list 2 itemCount = 2 and page 0.
3. PageView gets built with list 3 itemCount = 3 and page 2.
4. PageController.jumpToPage(2) gets called.
5. Page 2 gets displayed and then scrolls down automatically to page 1. (seems to think there is no page 2 and scrolls back to the last page when itemCount was 2)

I have tried calling jumpToPage(2) after the PageView gets built using WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(...) in the build method thinking that PageController was reading the old itemCount = 2 value somewhere. That did not work.

How do I get jumpToPage(2) to work based on the new PageView itemCount = 3 ?

Here is my code. I have tried to keep it as simple as possible.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePage2State createState() => _HomePage2State();
}

class _HomePage2State extends State<HomePage2> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> following = [
    {'title': 'Page 1 of 1 following', 'color': Colors.purple.value},
  ];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> suggested = [
    {'title': 'Page 1 of 2 suggested', 'color': Colors.purple.value},
    {'title': 'Page 2 of 2 suggested', 'color': Colors.red.value},
  ];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> trending = [
    {'title': 'Page 1 of 3 trending', 'color': Colors.purple.value},
    {'title': 'Page 2 of 3 trending', 'color': Colors.red.value},
    {'title': 'Page 3 of 3 trending', 'color': Colors.orange.value},
  ];

  String currentFeed = 'suggested';

  int followingCurrentPosition = 0;
  int suggestedCurrentPosition = 0;
  int trendingCurrentPosition = 0;

  PageController _pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build');
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
        (_) => _pageController.jumpToPage(getCurrentFeedPosition()));
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
        itemCount: getCurrentFeed().length,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        controller: _pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 1),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          print('PageView itemBuilder');
          return Container(
            color: Color(getCurrentFeed()[index]['color']),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Text(getCurrentFeed()[index]['title']),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () => changeCurrentFeed(),
                    child: Text('Change Feed'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void changeCurrentFeed() {
    setState(
      () {
        if (currentFeed == 'following') {
          followingCurrentPosition = _pageController.page.floor();
          currentFeed = 'suggested';
        } else if (currentFeed == 'suggested') {
          suggestedCurrentPosition = _pageController.page.floor();
          currentFeed = 'trending';
        } else {
          trendingCurrentPosition = _pageController.page.floor();
          currentFeed = 'following';
        }
      },
    );
  }

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> getCurrentFeed() {
    if (currentFeed == 'following') {
      return following;
    } else if (currentFeed == 'suggested') {
      return suggested;
    } else {
      return trending;
    }
  }

  int getCurrentFeedPosition() {
    if (currentFeed == 'following') {
      return followingCurrentPosition;
    } else if (currentFeed == 'suggested') {
      return suggestedCurrentPosition;
    } else {
      return trendingCurrentPosition;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior seems to be caused by PageView itemBuilder being called more than once per build. Others have had this issue but I was not able to find a solution. I ended up using a separate PageView for each list instead of trying to use one PageView with multiple lists. That fixed it for me.